# バッチで自動化する方法を知りたい

Tags: python, python3, batch-file

下記の作業をテキストエディタで正規表現を使用して整形していますが、バッチかなにかで自動化する方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

※バッチにこだわっているわけでなく、他に良い方法があればそちらでも構わないです。

(例)

```
ことば
いぬ
ねこ
```

①文字列の前後に`.*`, `.*|`を挿入

```
.*ことば.*|
.*いぬ.*|
.*ねこ.*|
```

②　①を横一列に整列

```
.*ことば.*|.*いぬ.*|.*ねこ.*|
```

Comment: 動作環境を明確にしてください。また使用言語も明確にされたほうがいいです。回答後にその言語は想定していなかったと言われるリスクがあるためです。ちなみに[tag:batch-file]はWindowsのBATファイルを指すため、暗にWindowsと特定された状態となっています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Python 3
li = ["kotoba","inu","neko"]
li2 = []
for s in li:
　　　s = ".*"+s+".*|"
     li2.append(s)
for s in li2:
     print(s)
#result: 
#.*kotoba.+|
#.*inu.+|
#.*neko.+|
print("".join(li2))
#result:.*kotoba.+|.*inu.+|.*neko.+|
```

Comment: 入力は改行付きですので、これを読み取る方法も一緒に記載すると親切かもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

pythonと外部モジュールを使える環境でしたら、pythonでバッチ処理を行う方法をご提案します。
下記はクリップボードを読み取って標準出力とクリップボード出力を行うサンプルコードです。

あらかじめ外部モジュール`pyperclip`のインストールが必要です。

#### python版

```
import pyperclip

src = pyperclip.paste()
# ToDo 下記の文字列はテストコードなので削除してください
src = '''ことば
いぬ
ねこ'''
dest = ''
for s in src.splitlines():
    dest += '.*{}.*|'.format(s)

# .*ことば.*|.*いぬ.*|.*ねこ.*|.*.*|.*表.*|
print(dest)          # コンソール出力
pyperclip.copy(dest) # クリップボード出力
```

pythonを使うことで`while`と`sleep`でクリップボードを監視する処理に変えたり、`argv`からコマンドライン引数を読み取ってテキストファイルやCSVファイルを処理するよう機能追加も可能です。

pythonや外部プログラムのインストールが許可されていない環境の場合は別回答となりますので、OSおよび入出力方法(ファイル入力して標準出力など)、運用方法(スケジュールで定期処理したいなど)と合わせて質問に追記なさってください。

---

`※バッチにこだわっているわけでなく、他に良い方法があればそちらでも構わない` 点と、手動でクリップボードにコピーしてから整形を行う運用をWindows10で行う点から、Powershellで整形してクリップボードに貼り付けるサンプルコードを追加します。

#### Powershell版

```
$src = Get-Clipboard
$sb = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
foreach($s in $src) { $sb.AppendFormat(".*{0}.*|", $s) > $null }
$dest = $sb.ToString()
$dest
# .*ことば.*|.*いぬ.*|.*ねこ.*|
Set-Clipboard $dest
```

Comment: payanecoさん　ありがとうございます。


pythonについては、許可が必要です。colaboratoryだと可能ですが。
colaboratoryではできませんかね。ただ先程試しましたがうまくいかなかったです


OS:win10
入出力方法:
①対象KWが入ったリストを、質問にあるように整形して、クリップボードに保存したい。
②その後既定の場所にてペースト。

②については私が手動でおこないます。

運用方法:タスクがあるときだけスポットで処理したい。

Comment: Google Colaboratoryでは[できません](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53234480)。Webブラウザ上で動作するアプリケーションなので、Pyperclipを使ってOS標準のクリップボードへアクセスすることはセキュリティ等の要件から制限されています。Powershell版の別回答での対応を検討されてはいかがでしょうか。なおコメントで環境や運用の詳細をいただきましたが、今回の質問は「テキストエディタで行っている手作業をバッチファイルやpythonで半自動化する方法」にフォーカスされていると感じました。質問文やコメントから「対象KW」「タスク」「スポット」とは何か、「リスト」の様式は何かが私には読み取れませんでした。「試しましたがうまくいかなかった」エラー内容も分かりません。これらをすべて質問文に追記するとおそらく「範囲が絞り切れていない質問」になると予想されますので、何をするために何を試して何の問題が発生しているのかを問題ごとに切り分けて個別の質問を作成されることをお勧めします。

Comment: pythonのほうをやってみました。

一番先頭に

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`を追加したところ、

`.*ことば.*|.*いぬ.*|.*ねこ.*|`とターミナル上で表示はされますが、
クリップボードにコピーされません。

Comment: payanecoさん　できました！

実行のときに

python batch.pyとしてたのでこのようなエラーがでました。

これを

python3 batch.pyにすると問題なくクリップボードにコピーされました。

Answer (score -1):

> ※バッチにこだわっているわけでなく、他に良い方法があればそちらでも構わないです。

Windowsっぽいので
・エディタのマクロを使う
・EXCELを開いて張り付け、VBAマクロや、セル連結でほしい形を作ってコピペする
・言語のマクロを覚えなくても、キーボードマクロで簡略化する